# Python generic multiprocess (no childrens)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I either having a hard time understanding the logic of the multiprocess library or I'm missing something.

Are the following two statements correct?

1. Excluding SharedMemoryManager, the multiprocess library does not provides any way to share data between processes, unless said processes are the children spawned by your original process via the library itself.
2. A multiprocess.Manager spawns a server process that manages the shared object (i.e. it doesn't use shared memory).

The first point is an inference based on the signature of the constructors I've seen, but I am not sure I am correct because it would mean most of the library is useless in the most generic case of multiprocessing (i.e. when the processes are not children of your main process).

If I'm correct multiprocess is basically a weird threading library that uses processes instead of threads due to the problem of the GIL...

The second point comes from the official docs, but it looks horribly inefficient compared to a shared memory approach, so I suspect I misunderstood.

If I am correct, though, then I have a last question:

3. Is there a more advanced version of the, very basic, SharedMemoryManager (even in a different library)? Something more like boost::interprocess. Something that could allocate in shmem and manage for me something like the CrossProcessDict from the example:

```
# Imagine I make this hashable by defining __eq__ and __hash__
@dataclass
class Key:
  field1: str
  field2: str

# Only some member functions will be "public".
# Those will be the ones taking care of the locking.
@dataclass
class Value:
  _array: List[float]
  _num1: int
  _num2: int
  _multiprocess_lock: Lock

@dataclass
class CrossProcessDict:
  my_dict1: Dict[Key, Value]
  my_dict2: Dict[Key, Value]
```

Comment: You say, "most of the library is useless in the most generic case of multiprocessing (i.e. when the processes are not children of your main process)." It is precisely that situation where processes are *supposed* to be protected from the prying eyes of other processes. There are still mechanisms for them to communicate (sockets, `SyncManager`, etc), but in a more secure, controlled fashion. On my shared server, my ISP has prevented shared memory services all together. My guess is the ISP is concerned that if you can guess a shared memory key you can look into another user's memory.

Comment: There's plenty of cases where you don't have a choice, and others where you would still choose a named shared memory section, which I think is why the library provides the SharedMemoryManager object. The problem is that's too simplistic for my usecase, from what I've understood from its docs.